# How to access ASP.NET session state given the session ID alone?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session-state

We have an ASP.NET application that uses session state. Incoming requests have the ASP.NET session ID cookie, and this allows the internals of ASP.NET to set HttpContext.Session, ready to be used by request handling code in e.g. aspx pages.

Now consider a custom HTTP handler that handles requests with no cookies and a session ID conveyed via a query parameter (this would be encrypted). The absence of the session ID cookie means that the standard ASP.NET handling cannot set HttpContext.Session. Is there some way that we can access the session state directly given the session ID from the query parameter?

Comment: Have you tried using the Cookieless session configuration?  [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178581(v=vs.140)#cookieless-sessionids) [Link2](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx)

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Thanks, that's definitely worth considering for anyone with the same problem that arrives here. I'm exploring other options because we would prefer to keep the http-only cookie for security reasons, i.e. it's within the encrypted https stream and not accessible to javascript.

Comment: Another option worth a mention is to implement a http module that decrypts the query param payload and injects the session ID cookie into HttpRequest.Cookies. This should work if the module is configured early enough in the ASP.NET request handling pipeline, i.e. before the standard ASP.NET logic that reads the session cookie and connects the HttpContext with session state.

Comment: You could also write a custom OnAcquireRequestState event handler [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateutility.getsessionstaticobjects?view=netframework-4.8)